# Issue with exporting list based pandas dataframe to Excel

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a series of dataframes which I am exporting to excel within the same file. A number of them appear to be stored as a list of dictionaries due to the way they have been constructed. I converted them using `.from_dict`. but when I use the `df.to_excel` an error is raised.

An example of one of the df's which is raising the error is shown below. My code:

```
excel_writer = pd.ExcelWriter('My_DFs.xlsx')

df_Done_Major = df[
                (df['currency_str'].str.contains('INR|ZAR|NOK|HUF|MXN|PLN|SEK|TRY')==False) & 
                (df['state'].str.contains('Done'))
                ][['Year_Month','state','currency_str','cust_cdr_display_name','rbc_security_type1','rfq_qty','rfq_qty_CAD_Equiv']].copy()

# Trades per bucket
df_Done_Major['Bucket'] = pd.cut(df_Done['rfq_qty'], bins=bins, labels=labels)
# Polpulate empty buckets with 0 so HK, SY and TK data can be pasted adjacently
df_Done_Major_Fill_Empty_Bucket = df_Done_Major.groupby(['Year_Month','Bucket'], as_index=False)['Bucket'].size()
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df_Done_Major_Fill_Empty_Bucket.index.levels[0], df_Done_Major['Bucket'].cat.categories])
df_Done_Major_Fill_Empty_Bucket  = df_Done_Major_Fill_Empty_Bucket.reindex(mux, fill_value=0)
dfTemp = df_Done_Major_Fill_Empty_Bucket
display(dfTemp)
dfTemp = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dfTemp)
display(dfTemp)
# Export
dfTemp.to_excel(excel_writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=0, startcol=21, na_rep=0, header=True, index=True, merge_cells= True)

2018-05  0K          0
         10K         2
         20K         4
         40K        10
         60K         3
         80K         1
         100K       14
         > 100K    273
dtype: int64
```

[image]

```
TypeError: Unsupported type <class 'pandas._libs.period.Period'> in write()
```

Even though I have converted to df is there additional conversion required?

**Update**: I can get the data into the excel using the following but the format of the dataframe is lost, which means significant excel vba to resolve.

```
list = [{"Data": dfTemp}, ]
```

[image]

Comment: This is a [known bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/19242). Can't find a duplicate so will keep this open.

Comment: The other issue here which differentiate my issue with the other post is that I need all my dataframes in the same file. I can't have a file for normal dataframes and another for those bult on lists

Comment: `I need all my dataframes in the same file`. This seems like a *different* issue to the `TypeError`. In my opinion, you should separate your 2 questions are they are not connected, you'll more likely get answers that way.

Comment: can you provide `dfTemp`? hard to replicate your error on just knowing `dfTemp = df_Done_Major_Fill_Empty_Bucket`

Comment: Updated the question to show how I construct one of the dataframes

Comment: Im python, is there a way to iterate through each line in the df, change format and append?